# C# separation to tab separation

Tags: c#

How do I change the space separation to tab separation.

Because [ LD Port 02 CSTID F7SC67: Sorts Complete. ] has a lot of space separation.

So I can’t split through Split !

```
List<string> add_list = new List<string>();
List<string> ok_list = new List<string>();
IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines("C:\\Users\\USER\\Downloads\\1231231231.log");

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    add_list.Add(line);
}

foreach (string row in add_list)
{
    var data = row.Split(' ');
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

Edit (by @chase): OP does not want to split by just spaces - this is why their code is wrong. Their final outcome should be the one mentioned in `What I want:` - where each item is separated by a comma and each item is clearly distinct. The input to reach this outcome is mentioned in `Data:`

Comment: Loop through data and use the [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1) method to write it's output into a variable (e.g. `string rowString`). Distinction checks could be done while looping - you did not really explain what your definition of 'distinct' is in this case.

Comment: The input is fixed width data and not tab delimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<string>> data = GetFixedWidth(FILENAME);
        }
         static List<List<string>> GetFixedWidth(string filename)
         {
             int[] startPosition = { 0, 6, 15, 24 }; 
             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
             string line = "";
             int length = 0;
             List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();
             while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
             {
                 line = line.Trim();
                 if(line.Length > 0)
                 {
                     List<string> rowList = new List<string>();
                     data.Add(rowList);
                     for (int i = 0; i < startPosition.Length; i++)
                     {
                         if (line.Length > startPosition[i])
                         {
                             if (i == startPosition.Length - 1)
                             {
                                 string lastColumn = line.Substring(startPosition[i]);
                                 if (lastColumn.Contains(":"))
                                 {
                                     string[] splitData = line.Substring(startPosition[i]).Split(new char[] { ':' });
                                     foreach (string split in splitData)
                                     {
                                         rowList.Add(split.Trim());
                                     }
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     rowList.Add(lastColumn);
                                 }
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 length = startPosition[i + 1] - startPosition[i];
                                 rowList.Add(line.Substring(startPosition[i], length).Trim());
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }

             return data;
         }
    }


}
```

Comment: Try Error: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. , Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: Sorry, Actually I don’t understand, its principle.

Comment: I updated code to handle blank lines and lines that may not contain all the columns.  I'm using the string substring method to extract the data as fixed width data where each column starts at a know character position in the line.

Comment: I don't think i need '.Split(new char[] { ':' })'
ex. "2", "00:00:50", "Normal", "LD Port 02 CSTID F7SC67  : Sorts Complete."

Comment: I updated code to handle when last column doesn't have a colon.